# C++ exception and ld symbol warning

Tags: c++, exception, ld, icc

I am playing with creating exceptions in C++ and I have the following test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class Myerror : public runtime_error {
    private: 
        string errmsg;
    public:
        Myerror(const string &message): runtime_error(message) { }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    throw Myerror("wassup?");
}
```

I am compiling this with:

> icpc -std=c++11 -O3 -m64

Upon compilation I am getting this ld warning:

> ld: warning: direct access in _main to global weak symbol
>   __ZN7MyerrorD1Ev means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being
>   compiled with different visibility settings.

I do not get this warning if I use g++ instead of icpc.

I have not been able to understand what this means, and what is causing this warning to generate. The code runs as expected, however I'd like to undesratand what is happening.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: Did you try it to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden`?

Comment: @jotep Including string didn't change anything.

Comment: @user2155932 Thanks, that helped! What did the command do? And why was symbol visibility an issue only in the case of the example above, but not for any other code that I have compiled?

Comment: @deepak Well, looks like it's exactly as it says: different translation units was being compiled with different visibility settings. Most likely, some of your libs (probably, libstdc++) has been compiled with `-fvisibility=hidden`. g++ compiles with hidden visibility by default.

Comment: @user2155932 Interesting, looks like I need to understand the symbol visibility concept more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class Myerror : public runtime_error {
    public:
        Myerror(const string &message) throw(): runtime_error(message) { }
        virtual ~Myerror() throw() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    throw Myerror("wassup?");
}
```

Why do you need unused string errmsg?